# How do you convert the bytes property from Objective-C to Swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c

I have a simple Objective-C function:

```objectivec
- (NSData *)xorData1:(NSData *)data1 data2:(NSData *)data2 resultLength:(NSInteger)length {
    const char *data1Bytes = [data1 bytes]; // ??
    const char *data2Bytes = [data2 bytes]; // ??

    NSMutableData *xorData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        const char xorByte = data1Bytes[i % data1.length] ^data2Bytes[i % data2.length];
        [xorData appendBytes:&xorByte length:1];
    }
    return xorData;
}
```

I need to make it work in Swift. How can I do this?

```swift
import CommonCrypto

func xor(firstData: Data, secondData: Data) -> Data {
    let length = kCCKeySizeAES128
    let firstDataBytes = firstData // ??
    let secondDataBytes = secondData // ??
    let xorData = NSMutableData()
    for i in 0..<length {
        var xorByte = firstDataBytes[i % firstData.count] ^ secondDataBytes[i % secondData.count];
        xorData.append(&xorByte, length: 1)
    }
    return xorData as Data
}
```

Comment: There is no `bytes` implementation... See lines with `// ??`

Comment: You have an idea how can it be simplified? Please share it if you know it. Thank you... You deleted your answer... Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Swift function compiles, and should produce the same results as the Objective-C function. A `bytes` property is not needed since `Data` is a `Collection` and the underlying bytes can be accessed by subscript:

```
let d = Data([11, 22, 33, 44, 54])
print(d[2]) // 33
```

There is also no need to use the Cocoa class `NSMutableData`, it is simpler to work with the Swift `Data` type throughout:

```
func xor(firstData: Data, secondData: Data) -> Data {
    let length = kCCKeySizeAES128
    var xorData = Data()
    for i in 0..<length {
        let xorByte = firstData[i % firstData.count] ^ secondData[i % secondData.count];
        xorData.append(xorByte)
    }
    return xorData
}
```

Or, using the `map` function:

```
func xor(firstData: Data, secondData: Data) -> Data {
    let length = kCCKeySizeAES128
    return Data((0 ..< length).map {
        firstData[$0 % firstData.count] ^ secondData[$0 % secondData.count]
    })
}
```